# Google maps API JS - omit zoom 18

Tags: javascript, function, api, google-maps, zooming

Good morning,
I want use google map on my website.
important settings:
maxZoom: 19,
minZoom: 14
I do not want to display the zoom 18. 
I'd like to set that when you change the zoom from 17 -> 18, I want 17 -> 19
and conversely 19 -> 17.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
   if (map.getZoom() == 18)
 {
   map.setZoom(19);
 }
});
```

from 17 -> 19 is it OK, but from 19 -> 17 It does not work properly

Thank you

Comment: Can you display some of your code to show your effort? That gives more context and makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the previous zoom as well as the current zoom.

```
var prev_zoom = 17;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = map.getZoom();
  if (map.getZoom() == 18 && prev_zoom == 17) {
    map.setZoom(19);
  } else if (map.getZoom() == 18 && prev_zoom == 19) {
    map.setZoom(17)
  }
  prev_zoom = map.getZoom();
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wcqamwLb/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var prev_zoom = 17;
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = map.getZoom();
    if (map.getZoom() == 18 && prev_zoom == 17) {
      map.setZoom(19);
    } else if (map.getZoom() == 18 && prev_zoom == 19) {
      map.setZoom(17)
    }
    prev_zoom = map.getZoom();
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="zoom"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```